# Setar variável mysql com o nome {parametro1}

Tags: mysql

A forma de setar uma variável no mysql é assim:

```
SET @variavel = valor
```

Na [Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) fala que a nome da variável pode conter outros caracteres, e no caso deve ser setada assim `SET @'variavel' = valor`.

É possível criar variável mysql contendo os caracteres `{` e `}` ?

Comment: Qual o motivo de minha pergunta ser negativada? Qual a justificativa para isso? O que fiz de errado? Fale para que eu possa corrigir.

Comment: é normal, eu tb tenho um negativo na resposta sem explicação. Mas isso nao muda muita coisa, positivos valem 5 em pergunta e 10 em resposta, negativos descontam só 2. Mas é bom pra gente repensar onde melhorar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após gastar alguns segundos fazendo um teste, obtive a seguinte resposta:

**Sim, é possível**

O teste:

```
set @'{banana}' = 10;
select @'{banana}'
```

O resultado:

```
10
```

Veja o teste feito e rodando online no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/28546)**.

**Atualização:**

Só pra ter certeza que a documentação está correta :), testei sem as aspas e o resultado foi esse:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{banana} = 10' at line 1
```

Comment: Vou verificar se dá certo e volto.